# Sphinx 3 2.1 error when try to index sphinx.conf

Tags: indexing, mariadb, database-connection, sphinx, mariadb-10.4

I am new to Sphinx and try setting 'index' in sphinx.conf.

When I run command "indexer.exe --all --rotate  --config C:\sphinx\etc\sphinx.conf", I found the Error like this:

```
using config file 'c:\sphinx\etc\sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'warehouse1'...
ERROR: index 'warehouse1': first column in SQL query result must be document ID; found 'code_attr' attribute instead.
total 0 docs, 0.0 Kb
total 0.0 sec, 0.0 Kb/sec, 0 docs/sec
```

this is my sphinx.conf

```
source warehouse
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = sphinx
    sql_pass        = sphinx_password
    sql_db          = test
    sql_port        = 3306  

    sql_query_pre = SELECT @id := 0
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT @id := @id + 1 AS code_attr, whse_id, whse_desc \
        FROM warehouse

    sql_attr_uint   = code_attr
    sql_field_string = whse_id
    sql_field_string = whse_desc
}


index warehouse1
{
    source      = warehouse
    path            = C:\sphinx\data\warehouse1
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = C:\sphinx\log\searchd.log
    query_log       = C:\sphinx\log\query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file        = C:\sphinx\logsearchd.pid
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = C:\sphinx\data
}
```

in my MariaDB, I have a table name 'warehouse' which contain fields like this:

```
whse_id   varchar(8) --> Primary Key
whse_desc varchar(40)
```

how can I fix this error?  please recommend more Sphinx knowledge I should read more. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the 1st column should be an id of your document.

Here:

```
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT @id := @id + 1 AS code_attr, whse_id, whse_desc \
        FROM warehouse

    sql_attr_uint   = code_attr
```

you are assigning it to the attribute. This is wrong, you need to select from the db the id and separately code_attr if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

@Manticore Search

I edit my sphinx.conf as you mentioned like this:

```
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id , whse_id, whse_desc \
        FROM warehouse

    sql_attr_uint   = id
    sql_field_string = whse_id
    sql_field_string = whse_desc
```

and the mariaDB table like this:

```
id bigint(11) unsigned --> Primary
whse_id  varchar(8)
whse_desc varchar(40)
```

but the error still occur

```
ERROR: index 'warehouse1': first column in SQL query result must be document ID; found 'id' attribute instead.
```

Comment: Remove `sql_attr_uint   = id`. The idea is: the 1st column in the result should be an id and it doesn't require any sql_attr_* or such. It just should be in the 1st column. Here's an interactive course about indexing from MySQL https://play.manticoresearch.com/mysql/ It's about Manticore, but in Sphinx it works exactly the same way.